# Sending a List or Array to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an api method to add Result from a Textfile.. My app reads data from text file and populate a generic list of C# Structure call ResultLines. When testing app when inspecting the request the Results line added as boby parameters and to the request I am using Restsharp to comsume my api.. But when i put a breakpoint on my api i can only see that 23 lines has been recieve but values are always null by expanding the model which i marked as bold

Here my code to consume the Api

```
    public HeatResultResponse AddHeatWithList(List<ResultFileLine> rec,string HeatNum, string WebApiUrl)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(WebApiUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest("Controller/InsertNewHeatList", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/form-urlencoded");
        //client.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("HeatNumber", HeatNum);
        rec.ForEach(r =>
           request.AddParameter("ResultLines", r)
         );
        IRestResponse<HeatResultResponse> response2 = client.Execute<HeatResultResponse>(request);
        return response2.Data;
    }
```

My Api Method looks like this

```
    public GetHeatIdResponse InsertNewHeatList(**HeatResultInsertListRequest model**)
    {
        GetHeatIdResponse resp = new GetHeatIdResponse
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            Message = "",
            HeatId = 0
        };

        if (model == null)
        {
            resp.Message = "Request body is empty. Should contain JSON data";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Heat heat = new Heat();
                    foreach(ResultFileLine model1 in model.ResultLines)
                    {   
                       .... Here there is code to populate result to the Db

                    }

                }
            }
```

Here is my Model

```
public class HeatResultInsertListRequest : BaseRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<ResultFileLine> ResultLines { get; set; }
    public string HeatNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Api by default will allow only 4mb request data.

IIS by default will accept 26 mb.

so iis will accept request but your app will accept will only 4mb data. Thats why request object is coming as null

You can increase this by modifying MaxRequestLength in HttpRuntime in Web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000"></httpRuntime>
```

Comment: Am still gettiing the same results even if i have added this line on the Web config file

Comment: check your data size, how much u are sending as request

Comment: When inspecting the Restsharp request i can see size=23 which is actual the number line in list and Capacity=32

Comment: Try to store request json in a file using json serializer and see the size